# Prepared statement inserting String " " into database instead of null

Tags: java, prepared-statement, jtextfield

my problem here is that if i try to leave blank spaces in my app, this code inserts an empty string into database on lines txtIme.getText() and txtPrezime.getText() and for that reason my if statement doesn't recognize .executeUpdate() as 0 and therefore doesn't print that nothing has been changed. Can I somehow change it so the app can reach my if statement if blank spaces are left in JTextField? Thank you.

```
    private void btnDodajActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {

        izraz = veza.prepareStatement("insert into autor (ime,prezime)" + "value (?,?)");

        izraz.setString(1, txtIme.getText());
        izraz.setString(2, txtPrezime.getText());



        if (izraz.executeUpdate()== 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getRootPane(), "Nothing was changed.");

        } else {
            ucitajIzBaze();
            ocistiPolja();
        }

        izraz.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: If you want to not insert rows in your database when your strings are empty, why check if the strings are empty with an `if` statement, and then just skip the insertion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you dont want to use any lib

```
private void btnDodajActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {

        if(txtIme.getText() == null || "".equals(txtIme.getText())) return;
        if(txtPrezime.getText() == null || "".equals(txtPrezime.getText())) return;
        izraz = veza.prepareStatement("insert into autor (ime,prezime)" + "value (?,?)");


        izraz.setString(1, txtIme.getText());
        izraz.setString(2, txtPrezime.getText());



        if (izraz.executeUpdate()== 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getRootPane(), "Nothing was changed.");

        } else {
            ucitajIzBaze();
            ocistiPolja();
        }

        izraz.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

But I recommend use any library for string related operations like

```
if(StringUtils.isBlank(txtIme.getText())) return;
if(StringUtils.isBlank(txtPrezime.getText())) return;
```

It in apache common lang package.

Comment: Thanks, with a couple of changes to the code, it worked like a charm!

Comment: Your welcome.
But you should not ask such question here. You should have done research from your end itself .